# Why do I have to add a decimal to get this math correct in C++

Tags: c++, division, integer-division

I was calculating the volume of a sphere and after tons of research I found that I cannot use:

```
float sphereRadius = 2.33;
float volSphere = 0;
volSphere = (4/3) * (M_PI) * std::pow(sphereRadius, 3);
```

But must add the `3.0` instead to get the right answer.

```
volSphere = (4/3.0) * (M_PI) * std::pow(sphereRadius, 3);
```

Why must a decimal be added to get the correct calculation?

Comment: lookup integer division... must be hundreds of duplicates

Comment: Expressions involving only integers are performed as integers operations and with an integer result.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`(4/3)` is one `integer` divided by another `integer`, which results in another `integer`. An `integer` can't be `1.33` or anything like that, so it gets truncated to `1`. With the decimal, you're telling it to be a `double` instead, and dividing an `integer` by a `double` results in a `double`, which supports fractions.

Comment: s/rounded/truncated/ ;)

Comment: Haha yep, "truncated" is indeed the correct term here. "rounded" could be misunderstood... it never actually rounds up positive numbers. Thanks for the hint, I added it to the answer.